# How can distant calulate query convert to django base?

Tags: python, django

How can I convert bellow this query base on django model?

```
select name,CAST((6371 * acos(cos(radians(37.51902684888236)) * cos(radians(Lat)) * cos(radians(Lon) - radians(127.10458919288556)) + sin(radians(37.51902684888236))* sin(radians(Lat)))) * 1000 as Int) as distance from station
```

This query calculate searching for nearest station.

For example Django model.

```
class Station(models.Model):
    Id      = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Name    = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    Lat     = models.FloatField()
    Lon     = models.FloatField()
```

How can I get the working code based on django model?

Answer (score 1):

Since you referred django models so I would suggest you to dive into geo django specially designed to handle geo related stuff. Here is reference for calculating distance between 2 points [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries).

If you dont wanna make such changes in configurations and use existing setup, then I would suggest to write sql for the same rather than python as you might need more filtering or ordering which will have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. And then before I checked django geo examples. But I don't wannna change field type.

Comment: In that case you can add a new field and use before save method to create a PointField instance using latitude and longitude and save the same.

Comment: There are tons of examples for the same. Like this one  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73322/geodjango-using-lat-lon-to-buffer-from-point

Comment: I use mysql. so engine set django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql. but occurt to error about Distance operations not available on this spatial backend.

Comment: Is using raw sql current best option?

Comment: I would totally go with geo django and use raw sql whenever i reach the boundry conditions and optimization. Regarding the error you are facing, it might be possible you dont have geo spatial libraries in your system. Please follow the instruction manual for the same https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/. Let me know if you face any further issues. Please accept the answer if this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: I used MariaDB. Anyway, Django GeoQuerySet does not support the mysql engine. Thank you for your kindly answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#geoqueryset-methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about databases to give you a satisfying answer, but it seems like you have a database engine that is specifically engineered for calculations.
I don't think Django's ORM is built to handle this specific database language.

You could take a look at the Django documentation about [aggregating functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions) and if that doesn't work, you can always fall back to [performing raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/) in Django.

Personally, I would execute the calculations in Python though. In that case you just need to get the variables you want and use Python's [math library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) to execute the calculation.

I hope this gives you some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Please read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/. I would highly contradict your opinion realted to Django ORM not designed for Geo queries.

Comment: @Tarun Thank you for your reply. I gave a +1 on your answer, since it is obviously better than mine ^_^